# Cypher query in a neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphdb, property-graph

I have the following graph in Neo4j: 
**Book**: book_id, isbn, language_code, title, image_url, small_image_url, avg_ratings, 
**Author**: name, 
**Reader**: id, 
with 3 relationships: 
**(Reader)-[:Rated]->(Book)** that has the property {rating: value}, 
**(Reader)-[:Recommend]->(Book)**, 
**(Author)-[:Write]->(Book)**. 

I want to find the book that has been most recommended with a query in Cypher. 
I wrote a query but I'm not too sure about it because I'm not familiar using count() and max() operators.

Here is my attempt:

```
MATCH (r:Reader) - [rel:recommend] -> (b:Book) 
RETURN count(rel), b 
ORDER BY count 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please include your attempt.

Comment: MATCH (r:Reader) - [r:recommend] -> (b:Book) RETURN count(r), b ORDER BY count LIMIT 1

Comment: Well, the variable `r` is confused: does it refer to Readers or the recommend relationship? You should get a syntax error with this one. You also might need to ORDER BY DESC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
MATCH (:Reader) - [:recommend] -> (b:Book) 
RETURN 
    count(1) AS `Number of Recommendations`, 
    b AS `Book`
ORDER BY `Number of Recommendations` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I would leave off the `LIMIT` clause until you make sure it's doing what you want. I don't have your database, so I can't test this, but maybe this will work as a first stab at it.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't understand how count(1) can count the number of racommendations for each book.

Comment: And why do you put DESC?

Comment: You need DESC to arrange the values in descending order so that the first one is the largest. `count(1)` simply counts according to the grouping - in this case by book. It's usually a bit faster to do `count(1)` than to do `count(r)`. I have tested a version of this code on a Neo4j database to which I have access, and it works.